# People Picker Control in Sharepoint Framework web part (No Javascript Framework)

Tags: spfx, people-picker

I am new to SPFx and have a SPFx web part form project with No JavaScript framework option. In this I need to implement a People picker. I need to implement the form both as a new and edit form i.e in new mode the people picker will be used to select a user and in edit mode it will fetch details from a sharepoint list and populate the people picker with the user details.

I have been following the microsoft spfx development thread :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the form done and people picker integrated using sppeoplepicker js. Sharing my learnings and how i got it done in my blog:

[Custom Form Using SPFX (No Javascript Framework)](https://366pi.tech/custom-sharepoint-form-using-spfx-no-javascript-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use fabric UI People picker in your project. Follow the link for detailed instructions:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/peoplepicker

Comment: This is example is not specific for No JavaScript Framework. This is in react.

Comment: Yes. Need something for No Javascript Framework.